# How to add only its own classes to a jar file without subpackages using ant script?

Tags: java, ant

Let's say my package organization is like below:

net.sf.myparentpackage

- class: requiredclass1.java
- class: requiredclass2.java

net.sf.test.mysuppackage

- class: notrequiredclass1.java

The code below includes all classes and subpackages.

```
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" manifest="MANIFEST.MF">
  <fileset dir=".." includes="net/sf/myparentpackage/**"
</jar>
```

I want to include only requiredclass1.java and requiredclass2.java without listing all class names.

Comment: So you want to build a JAR containing only `requiredclass1.java` and `requiredclass2.java` ?

Comment: I want to include all parent package content without subpackages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by put "*.java" or "*.class" instead of "**"

```
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" manifest="MANIFEST.MF">
  <fileset dir=".." includes="net/sf/myparentpackage/*.java"
</jar>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html